# MySQL - group by for counting except null

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I'm trying to make a chart for my board. 
But I have no idea how I can count the number of the article_id only if it is not null.

In the below, if article_id is null, it should not be counted.
How can I fix this?

```
mysql> select article_id, count(*) as count from board group by article_id order by count desc limit 3;
+------------+-------+
| article_id | count |
+------------+-------+
|       NULL |     7 |
|         12 |     3 |
|          3 |     2 |
+------------+-------+
3 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Filter out nulls with a `WHERE article_id IS NOT NULL`

Comment: Thank you so much!

Answer (score 3):

```
select article_id, count(*) as count 
from board 
where  
article_id is not null
group by article_id 
order by count desc limit 3
```

Answer (score 1):

you should try 
    mysql> select article_id, count(*) as count from board group by article_id where article_is is not null order by count desc limit 3;